# What to choose for an RF spectrum analyzer A/D conversion

Tags: rf, dsp, fft

I assigned myself a (long term) project to build an RF spectrum analyzer. In the basis it will be a super or triple (depending on frequency band) heterodyne frontend with digitized IF and some final filtering and FFT (FPGA/CPU). The idea is to add demodulation options in a later stage.
I am a bit in doubt what would be the best approach for the A/D stage. The chosen A/D converter fs will be around 120 MHz.
This allows an IF bandwidth of approx. 50MHz but imposes a steep anti alias filter.

Another option is to limit the IF bandwidth to 30MHz, so we have oversampling and  decimate in the digital domain.

Advantages of the last option:

- Theoretically slightly lower A/D noise floor.
- Easier anti-alias filtering.
- Reduced sample rate for digital filters and FFT

Disadvantages:

- Slower sweep time (as Spectrum analyzer)
- Half of the real time display bandwidth.

Currently I tend to go for the oversampling option.  Is there any reason why this could be a bad idea for a spectrum analyzer ?

Comment: How is this different from an SDR front end?

Comment: In principle not, although the requirement might be a bit different. Spurious signals might be of less importance for someone who is using an SDR just as a receiver for specific signals, whereas for a spectrum analyzer spurs should be minimal.  For an SA dynamic range is important, which might be less of a concern for a receiver.

Comment: So are you going to use a fast ADC and an FPGA?